# ListView not populating with data

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Good day, 
I have a problem with my custom adapter not populating my listviews. I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.MyWorkout$1.onChildClick(MyWorkout.java:64)
```

Making me think my arraylist is empty.. this is where i call the adapter:

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> w29 = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
    w29.add(new CustomObject("Squat", "65%", "6", "150", false));

    final CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, w29);


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWorkouts);
    Workouts_details = DataProvider.getInfo();
    Workout_list = new ArrayList<>(Workouts_details.keySet());
    mAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(this, Workouts_details, Workout_list);

    final ListView listViewFri = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFri);
    final ListView listViewMon = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMon);
    final ListView listViewWed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWed);

    expandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    listViewMon.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
                    listViewFri.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
                    listViewWed.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkoutDaysActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<CustomObject> objects;
boolean[] checkBoxState;
CustomObject data[] = null;




private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtExercise;
    TextView txtPercent;
    TextView txtReps;
    TextView txtWeight;
    CheckBox check1;
}

public void addAdapterItem(CustomObject item) {
    objects.add(item);
}

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomObject> objects) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.objects = objects;
    checkBoxState= new boolean[objects.size()];
}

public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

public CustomObject getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
        holder.txtExercise = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtExercise);
        holder.txtPercent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
        holder.txtReps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtReps);
        holder.txtWeight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
        holder.check1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtExercise.setText(objects.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.txtPercent.setText(objects.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.txtReps.setText(objects.get(position).getReps());
    holder.txtWeight.setText(objects.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

    holder.check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
                checkBoxState[position] = true;
            } else {
                checkBoxState[position] = false;
            }
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
}
```

this is the customobject class:

```
public class CustomObject {

private String exercise;
private String percent;
private String reps;
private String weight;
private boolean check1;

public CustomObject(String exercise, String percent, String reps, String weight, boolean check1) {
    this.exercise = exercise;
    this.percent = percent;
    this.reps = reps;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.check1 = check1;
}

public String getExercise() {
    return exercise;
}

public String getPercent() {
    return percent;
}

public String getReps() {
    return reps;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

//    public CheckBox getCheck1() {
//        return check1;
//    }
}
```

this is part of the WorkoutDaysActivity (Where the intent is sent) (Ive included the on create method as well as the 3 tabs getting set up.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);


    mToolBar = activateToolbarWithHomeEnabled();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_days, container, false);
//                    CustomListViewAdapter mCustomListViewAdapter;
//                    mCustomListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, )
//                    ListView listViewMon = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewMon);
//                    listViewMon.setAdapter(mCustomListViewAdapter);


                return rootView;
            case 2: View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page1, container, false);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView2.setText("Workout 29 Week 1");
                return rootView2;
            case 3:
                View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page2, container, false);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootView3.findViewById(R.id.txtFrag3);
                textView3.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView3;
            default: View rootView4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_days, container, false);
                TextView textView4 = (TextView) rootView4.findViewById(R.id.txtFrag1);
                textView4.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView4;
        }
//
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear, one of listView objects is null:

```
final ListView listViewFri = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFri);
final ListView listViewMon = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMon);
final ListView listViewWed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWed);
```

check does views ids are correct

Comment: Thanks for answer, under where I set the adapter, I have an Intent that sends the app to a new class when child item clicked. In that class I have the content set to another layout. I think this may be where the problem lies. The listviews arent in either of those layouts, they are actually in the tab fragments that the childclick is sent to. I'm not sure how I can fix this. I will add in the question that activity.

Comment: I have added the Intent line in where Im trying to set the adapter, I also added the class that it sends the app to, and where the tabs are set up. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It says that the listviews are null, can you check your xml to make sure you are adding the listviews correctly. Can you also paste your code of your activity's onCreate or where you inflate the xml or do `setContentView` . You are not setting the view correctly. Your arraylists are fine and your adapter code also seems to be look fine

Comment: Thanks for answer, under where I set the adapter, I have an Intent that sends the app to a new class when child item clicked. In that class I have the content set to another layout.  I think this may be where the problem lies. The listviews arent in either of those layouts, they are actually in the tab fragments that the childclick is sent to. I'm not sure how I can fix this. I will add in the question that activity.

Comment: I have added the Intent line in where Im trying to set the adapter, I also added the class that it sends the app to, and where the tabs are set up. Thanks for help

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe I should be doing all this code in the switch argument where the tabs are set up. Only problem then is how do I let it know which item on the previous expandable list view was clicked, as each one will give different data.

Answer (score 0):

Error is quite simple.
While getting the reference of listView you are doing some mistake in writing the ID.
e.g. R.id.list(list is the ID here)

Maybe you are using some other reference which is not found in the .xml of your layout that you are using for that activity.